# Retrieve the value of a read-only input text box using VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript

I'm working with an Internet Explorer based application where I need to retrieve the value of an input text box that is read only. I've looked at other Stack Overflow questions and don't see anything about getting the value of a read only or hidden input box. I haven't found anything I can use on the internet either.

Here's the HTML code for the input box I'm trying to get the value from:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 form-field input_controls">
   <div class="hidden" ng-non-bindable="">
      <input name="sys_original.x_opt_im_issue_task.number" id="sys_original.x_opt_im_issue_task.number" type="hidden" value="TSK0111065" />
   </div>
   <input class="form-control disabled " id="sys_readonly.x_opt_im_issue_task.number" readonly="readonly" ng-non-bindable="" value="TSK0111065" />
</div>
```

Here's the VBScript code I'm trying to use to get the value of the input text box that isn't working:

**UPDATED**

```
Option Explicit

Dim WShell, objShell, objIE
Dim strMessage, URL, ErrMsg, URLFound, Browser
Dim EN_ID, EntNowID

Sub Main()
   On Error Resume Next
      Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then ShowError("Failed to create objects")
   On Error GoTo 0

   Check_EN

   SetEverythingToNothing
End Sub

'---------------------------------

Sub ShowError(strMessage)
   MsgBox strMessage & vbNewline & vbNewline & "Error number: " & Err.Number & vbNewline & "Source: " & Err.Source & vbNewline & "Description: " & Err.Description
   Err.Clear

   SetEverythingToNothing
End Sub

'------------------------------

Sub Check_EN()
   URL = "https://enterprisenow.mysite.com"
   ErrMsg = "EnterpriseNOW is not open or on the incorrect page. Please check & rerun the macro."

   Check_URL

   ErrMsg = ""

   Set EN_ID = objIE.document.getElementById("sys_readonly.x_opt_im_issue_task.number")
   EntNowID = EN_ID.Value

   MsgBox EntNowID
End Sub

'------------------------------

Function Check_URL()
   URLFound = False

   For Each Browser In objShell.Windows()
      If InStr(UCase(Browser.LocationURL), UCase(URL)) > 0 Then
         If InStr(UCase(Browser.FullName), "IEXPLORE.EXE") Then
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
               Set objIE = Browser
               URLFound = True
               Exit For
            End If
         End If
      End If
   Next

   If URLFound = False Then
      MsgBox "Unable to find URL."
      SetEverythingToNothing
   End If
End Function

'-----------------------------

Sub SetEverythingToNothing()

   Set WShell = Nothing
   Set objShell = Nothing
   Set Browser = Nothing
   Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm able to set the `objIE` object and find the `URL`, but I'm receiving `"Run-time error '424': Object required"`. Is it because the input text box is hidden or read only? I'm also wondering if it has anything to do with nested `div` tags?

Comment: looks like your `objShell` is not initialized.

Comment: `objShell` is initialized at the top of the code as `Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")`, I just didn't include it in the example to save space for readability. Also, it has to be initialized because I can find the `URL`, just can't access the number in the `input` field.

Comment: It helps to be complete enough, and certainly to mention clearly where you get an error.

Comment: I do apologize. I will have to remember that for next time. I thought I was clear after my example when I said "I'm able to set the `objIE` object and find the `URL`...". I didn't believe I needed to show initializing `objShell` as it would have shown error at the beginning of the `For...Next` loop. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not the solution I was hoping for, but it's easier than trying to get the number from the `input` field.

I had a feeling that the `iframe` tag may be preventing me from detecting the `input` field ID, so I looked at the `iframe` and saw that the TSK number in the `input` field was also in the `iframe` tag.

Instead of trying this:

```
EN_ID = objIE.document.getElementById("sys_readonly.x_opt_im_issue_task.number").Value
```

I was able to use this:

```
iframeName = Split(objIE.document.getElementById("gsft_main").Title, " | ")    'Title = "TSK0111065 | Issue Task | ServiceNow"
EN_ID = iframeName(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - it worked for me.  What I noticed is that if I accessed:

```
objIE.document.getElementById("sys_readonly.x_opt_im_issue_task.number").Value
```

more than once, I got the error: Object required

However if I used 'Set' and created an object like so:

```
Set tasknumber = objIE.document.getElementById("sys_readonly.x_opt_im_issue_task.number")
```

I could then access the value multiple times without receiving the error.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
Dim URL : URL = "https://enterprisenow.mysite.com/"
Dim URLFound : URLFound = False
Dim Browser, tasknumber, tasknumbervalue

For Each Browser In objShell.Windows()
    If InStr(UCase(Browser.FullName), "IEXPLORE.EXE") Then
        If InStr(UCase(Browser.LocationURL), UCase(URL)) > 0 Then   
            If Err.Number = 0 Then

                Set tasknumber = Browser.document.getElementById("sys_readonly.x_opt_im_issue_task.number")

                If (NOT IsNull(tasknumber) And NOT tasknumber Is Nothing) Then
                    tasknumbervalue = tasknumber.value
                End If

                Set tasknumber = Nothing                

                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

MsgBox tasknumbervalue

Set Browser = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I'm getting `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`. Any ideas why?

Comment: `Set EN_ID = objIE.document.getElementById("sys_readonly.x_opt_im_issue_task.number")`. I added `Set` in front of the line you mentioned and removed `.Value`, then stepped through the code and it keeps failing at that line.

Comment: Have you tried my script on its own?  In your example, have you assigned/declared EN_ID as something else previously?  I'd need to see more of the code.

Comment: I updated my code. Hopefully you'll be able to see what I can't.

Comment: When I copied your code, changed the URL to a local one (so I can test), it ran fine for me with no errors.  The only thing different is that I was testing a local web page with the normal html/head/body tags and your div structure.